# Дан текст. Сложить все имеющиеся в нем цифры

Tags: c++, строки

Программа, как понимаю, возвращает сумму ASCII найденных чисел, а как найти сумму самих чисел? Или есть вариант сделать как-то по-другому?

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        string userString;
        int sum = 0;
        cout << "Input the string: ";
        cin >> userString;
        
        cout << "Sum digits in the string: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (isdigit(userString.at(i))) 
            {
                sum += userString.at(i);            
            }
        }
        cout << sum;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Преобразовать символ в представляемое им число:

```
sum += userString.at(i) - '0';
```

Только я бы не использовал это `at` - зачем вам тут проверка на выход за границы строки? которую вы все равно не используете...

```
for (auto c: userString) 
    if (isdigit(c)) sum += c - '0';
```

И еще - учтите, что `>> string` читает слово, а не всю строку.

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо!